# Released APK contains plaintext

Tags: android

I have signed my APK now but if I open it up I can still see many things like websites I connect to, Stuff that is written in the APP etc. Is there anything that I should be aware of? On one hand this is needed to run the app, but is there any sensetive data included?

Comment: "but is there any sensetive data included?" -- how can we know? You are the one with the APK, based on the code that you wrote. We cannot see it.

Comment: Well you got a point, but I don't want to release the APK before I know. Is there any way to check? Or are the Strings always displayed in plaintext?

Answer (score 2):

proguard doesn't obfuscate strings.  [Dexguard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/dexguard) does, but you'll have to pay for it.